# Reactjs button UI not changing dynamically based on api data

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api

I am rendering either pause or resume button based on the "status" key's value that I am getting from an API call data. When I click on pause button I trigger an api call that changes the "status" key's value to something else and based on that I am conditionally rendering resume button.
Problem is after click on pause button I have to refresh page again to see resume button. It doesnt happen in real time. What is the problem and how to solve it?

`status: "Running"`
Above is the key that changes on click based on which different buttons are dynamically supposed to render but I have to refresh the page to see the change. Here is the button code:

```
{
                      data.status === "Running" ?
                        <button onClick={() => Pause(data)}>
                          Pause
                        </button> : ""
                    }
                     {
                      data.status === "Paused" ?
                        <button onClick={() => Resume(data)}>
                          Resume
                        </button> : ""
                    }
```

code for onclick dispatch calls:

```
 const Pause = (data) => {
    const datas = {
      learnerId: data.learner._id,
      pausePeriod: 7,
      timezone: "Asia/Calcutta"
    }
    const onSuccess = () => {
      alert("Plan paused successfully");
    }
    const onError = () => {
      alert("Somthing went wrong !!");

    }
    dispatch(PausePlan(datas, onSuccess, onError))

  }

  const Resume = (data) => {
    const datas = {
      learnerId: data.learner._id,
      timezone: "Asia/Calcutta"
    }
    const onSuccess = () => {
      alert("Plan resumed successfully");
    }
    const onError = () => {
      alert("Somthing went wrong !!");

    }
    dispatch(ResumePlan(datas, onSuccess, onError))

  }
```

whole component code:

```
import { Modal } from "react-bootstrap";
import { useSelector, useDispatch } from "react-redux";
import { getDate } from "../../../helpers/TimeDate";
import Loder from "../../loder";
import { UTCtoLocalConverter } from "../../../helpers/TimeDate";
import { PausePlan, ResumePlan } from "../../../redux/actions/PlanAction";
import { useSnackbar } from "react-simple-snackbar";


function SubscriptionModal(props) {
  const history = useSelector((state) => state.PlanReducer.planHistory);
  const [openSnackbar, closeSnackbar] = useSnackbar();
  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  console.log(history)
  function monthDiff(d1, d2) {
    var months;
    const date1 = new Date(d1)
    const date2 = new Date(d2)
    months = (date2.getFullYear() - date1.getFullYear()) * 12;
    months -= date1.getMonth();
    months += date2.getMonth();
    return months <= 0 ? 0 : months + " month";
  }

  const Pause = (data) => {
    const datas = {
      learnerId: data.learner._id,
      pausePeriod: 7,
      timezone: "Asia/Calcutta"
    }
    const onSuccess = () => {
      alert("Plan paused successfully");
    }
    const onError = () => {
      alert("Somthing went wrong !!");

    }
    dispatch(PausePlan(datas, onSuccess, onError))

  }

  const Resume = (data) => {
    const datas = {
      learnerId: data.learner._id,
      timezone: "Asia/Calcutta"
    }
    const onSuccess = () => {
      alert("Plan resumed successfully");
    }
    const onError = () => {
      alert("Somthing went wrong !!");

    }
    dispatch(ResumePlan(datas, onSuccess, onError))

  }
  return (
    <div>
      <Modal
        {...props}
        size="md"
        aria-labelledby="contained-modal-title-vcenter"
        centered
        className="sub"
      >
        <Modal.Body className="profile_modal_content">
          <h4>Subscription History</h4>
          <div>
            {history ? history[0] ? (
              history.map((data, i) => (
                <div className="card mt-4" style={{ height: "400px" }} key={i}>
                  <h3 className="text-center pb-0 mb-0">{data.plan.courseName}</h3>
                  <p className="text-center top">{i === 0 ? "Active" : "Not Active"}</p>
                  <div className="row">
                    <div className="col-6">
                      <div className="text-center">
                        <p className="top mb-0">Start Date:</p>
                        <p className="bottom">{data.isTimeUtc ? UTCtoLocalConverter(data.startDate) : getDate(data.startDate)}</p>
                      </div>
                      <div className="text-center">
                        <p className="top mb-0">Week Start Date:</p>
                        <p className="bottom">{data.isTimeUtc ? UTCtoLocalConverter(data.weekStart) : getDate(data.weekStart)}</p>
                      </div>
                      <div className="text-center">
                        <p className="top mb-0">Total Sessions:</p>
                        <p className="bottom">{data.totalSession}</p>
                      </div>
                      <div className="text-center">
                        <p className="top mb-0">Sessions This Week:</p>
                        <p className="bottom">{data.totalWeeklySession}</p>
                      </div>


                      <div className="text-center">
                        <p className="top mb-0">Frequency:</p>
                        <p className="bottom">{`${data.plan.frequency} days/week`}</p>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                    <div className="col-6">
                      <div className="text-center">
                        <p className="top mb-0">End Date:</p>
                        <p className="bottom">{data.isTimeUtc ? UTCtoLocalConverter(data.endDate) : getDate(data.endDate)}</p>
                      </div>
                      <div className="text-center">
                        <p className="top mb-0">Week End Date:</p>
                        <p className="bottom">{getDate(data.weekEnd)}</p>
                      </div>

                      <div className="text-center">
                        <p className="top mb-0">Total Sessions Left:</p>
                        <p className="bottom">{data.availableSession}</p>
                      </div>
                      <div className="text-center">
                        <p className="top mb-0">Sessions Left This Week:</p>
                        <p className="bottom">{data.availableWeeklySession}</p>
                      </div>
                      <div className="text-center">
                        <p className="top mb-0">Session Cancelled:</p>
                        <p className="bottom">{data.canceledSession}</p>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <p className="top text-center" style={{ fontWeight: "bolder", color: "red" }}>
                    {`Your ${data.availableWeeklySession} session going to expire at ${data.isTimeUtc ? UTCtoLocalConverter(data.weekEnd) : getDate(data.weekEnd)}`}
                  </p>
                  <div>
                    {
                      data.status === "Running" ?
                        <button onClick={() => Pause(data)}>
                          Pause
                        </button> : ""
                    }
                     {
                      data.status === "Paused" ?
                        <button onClick={() => Resume(data)}>
                          Resume
                        </button> : ""
                    }
                  </div>
                </div>
              ))
            ) : <div className="text-center">Subscription Histoty not available</div> : (
              <Loder />
            )}
          </div>
        </Modal.Body>
      </Modal>
    </div>
  );
}

export default SubscriptionModal;
```

Comment: Can you share the whole component?

Comment: Could you share a bit more, e.g. what is `data` and how it is updated?

Comment: I have added the onclick dispatch calls code. After clicking on button theres a call that updates the status value based on which i am conditionally rendering button but I have to refresh to see the change

Comment: please share the entire component that is rendering the buttons - especially what is `data` and how does the component obtain it

Comment: Okay I have added the whole component code now